# echo a div class

Tags: php, html

I have a problem, when I try to `echo` a div class. When I put the following code in my template, it detects only the closing tag and not the opening. So, my webpage is ruined:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="pagina_text">

        {{ CONTENT }}
        <br />
        <div class="rw-ui-container"></div>
        <br /><br />
        <?php
            var_dump($_GET['categorie']);
            if(isset($_GET['categorie']) && $_GET['categorie'] === "navigatie_bar")
            {
                echo "<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://alledaagsetips.nl\"  data-numposts=\"10\" data-colorscheme=\"light\"></div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div> <!-- end pagina_text -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Does someone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `$_GET['categorie']` is not equal to `navigatie_bar`? And that `$_GET['categorie']` is a string?

Comment: show so more code and change `</br>` to `<br>` or `<br />`

Comment: check the wrapping markup in which you put this markup. maybe there are other divs unclosed

Comment: I put the code in an empty html sheet and still got the same so it's not the rest of the code

Comment: I don't really know what you mean Daan, It should get the categorie from the URL and when it is navigatie_bar it should not echo.

Comment: The div is perfectly closing,there might be some other div unclosed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a binary-safe comparison (`strcmp`) instead of a regular string comparison?

Comment: This code snippet is working fine, so the problem is probably in the template itself. Of,  and you'd better add `isset($_GET['categories']) &&` to the beginning of you condition.

Comment: You can also try `var_dump($_GET['categorie']);` in your PHP to check what the variable contains.

Comment: can you post the html output? Have you tried to remove the if statement to ensure your echo statement is working correctly?

Comment: If i remove the if statement it is still the same problem.

Comment: i'm giving up.... been trying to fix this thing for a weeek now and nobody knows the anwser :(

Comment: my webpage puts out this line ' } ?> instead of the fb comment box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace single quote with double quote.

Change

```
<?php
if(strcmp($_GET['categorie'], "navigatie_bar") != 0)
{
echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl"  data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
}
?>
```

to this

```
<?php
if(strcmp($_GET['categorie'], 'navigatie_bar') != 0)
{
echo "<div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://alledaagsetips.nl'  data-numposts='10' data-colorscheme='light'></div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace single quotes with double and vice versa

```
echo "<div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://alledaagsetips.nl'  data-numposts='10' data-colorscheme='light'></div>";
```

or use the same for all but with backslash, just to not get confused

```
echo "<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://alledaagsetips.nl\"  data-numposts=\"10\" data-colorscheme=\"light\"></div>";
```

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "IF" condition is working?

Perhaps with a simple string comparison like so :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['categorie']) && $_GET['categorie'] === "navigatie_bar") {
    echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Still some problem :(

Comment: Try the code below and then copy/paste the result here. `<?php var_dump($_GET['categorie']); ?>`

Comment: I don't follow, you mean in need to put var_dump($_GET['categorie']); before the if(isset($_GET['categorie']) ?

Comment: Yes, it's a debug function that will help you find if the variable is set and also display its contents.

Comment: I did what you said but still nothing changes. Where can i see if the variable is set and see the contents ?

Comment: You should see the result of the `var_dump` in your page HTML. A link to page or a screenshot to see the result produce could help us find the origin of the problem.

Comment: I think i found a problem, can you take a look at this [link]http://pastebin.com/uZPmfrr6 it's the code in my template and it colors yellow in the middle.

Comment: I have tested the code and it's works for me. Have you put`?categorie=navigatie_bar` in the URL you try to reached ?

Comment: Yes i did. Still have the same problem. I don't understand why the div class doesn't get blue and fb-comments green. Because that is what happens to all the div classes in the template.

Comment: So the "div" is visible in your page. But your problem seem to be the color of this "div" ?

Comment: I use the program Jetbrains and all the div in the page are highlighted the same except the one in the echo

Comment: The program doesn't see the <div class"fb-comments" ..... > as an opening but it does see the </div> as a closing tag.

Comment: The color of the "div" in Jetbrains is probably correct. Indeed, this "div" is in an "" or '', so color correspond to a string.

Comment: my webpage puts out this line ' } ?> instead of the fb comment box

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="pagina_text">
        {{ CONTENT }}
         <br>
         <div class="rw-ui-container"></div>
         <br><br>
        <?php if ( ! empty($_REQUEST['categorie']) and $_REQUEST['categorie'] == 'navigatie_bar'): ?>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl"  data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </div> <!-- end pagina_text -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```